# A few questions about infinite derivative.

Tags: calculus

I've been having a few questions about infinite derivative for a long time now. I think to answer these questions involves dealing with properties of limit, hope someone can help. Thanks!

1). Does writing the derivative of a function as a function lose information? For example, the function $y = x^{1/3}$ has a derivative that evaluates to infinite at $x = 0$. But its derivative is undefined at the point, we only know it $\lim_{x\to0} y$ is infinite.

2). I know that most calculus textbooks consider having an infinite derivative to be not differentiable at that point, which means we are not allowed to apply chain rule and product rule. However, am I guaranteed to get a wrong answer if I apply them to cases where derivatives are infinite, or are there cases where it is still legal to do so(by the nature of dealing with infinite limits)?

3). The slope at $t = c$ on a curve defined by parametric equations $y = f(t)$ and $x = g(t)$ is $dy/dx = (dy/dt)/(dx/dt)$. When both $dy/dt$ and $dx/dt$ equals $0$ at $t = c$, the textbook applies l'Hospital's rule to find $\lim_{t\to c} dy/dx$ and thereby determines the slope at $t = c$. But why should we turn to find the limit of the derivative as $t\to c$ instead of the derivative itself at $t = c$?

Comment: Welcome to M.SE, I edit your question to add [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), you should use it from now on, it will make your question more clear and you will probably get more answers

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first $2$ questions is pretty much the same: **infinity is not a number**, there is no *at infinity*, when you say "the derivative of $x^{1/3}$ at $0$ is infinity" what do you mean? The derivative is defined as a function, $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$The derivative of $x^{1/3}$ is $\frac1{3x^{2/3}}$, which is undefined at $0$, when someone say "the derivative is infinity" it means it goes beyond every number, every real number that you take, say $M$, I can find a real number close enough to $0$, say $\delta$ such that for every $x$ that is between $\delta$ and $0$ we have $\frac1{3x^{2/3}}>M$.

About the third part, I have a question: what is $\frac00?$ For example, if I take the function $f(x)=|x|$, then it is "obvious" that $\frac{f(0)}{f(0)}=1$, but what if I take $\frac{f(0)}{-f(0)}?$ I will get $-1$ using this logic, this is because $0/0$ is one of the [Indeterminate forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form); this is why we have to take limit

Answer (score 0):

1) No, you can retrieve the function from the derivative by integration (to a constant), even with unbounded derivatives.

2) Algebra and calculus cease to apply where there are "infinite" values. Full stop. (In fact, if you try and use rules valid for bounded values, you will soon obtain incongruities.)

3) A derivative is *always* a limit, and the general computation rules for limits pertain.

I am afraid that you missed the essence of the theory of limits. Infinity is not a mathematical object.